# Is it possible to protect disk image, in format of dd, with bitlocker

Tags: hard-drive, dd, bitlocker, disk-image

I have some files on disk image. This image is in dd format. Now I want to protect that disk with bitlocker. How do I do this? I have tried mounting this image to windows with OSFMount tool, FTK Imager and ImgDisk. But bitlocker can not see this drive whenever software and settings I select. My original goal is to protect this image with bitlocker. Disk is in NTFS format.

I have both windows ultimate and linux lubuntu and file is on flash drive(so I have full access to tools from both worlds ). But I planning to work with this image from windows.

Comment: Bitlocker is disk encryptor. My file is disk image. I believe they should work together.

Comment: What OS are you using? Linux (dd) or Windows? (ntfs) I'll base my answer around this information

Comment: I have both  OS. Image was taken from Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like previously mentioned, you can convert the `.DD` image to `.VHD` then mount it in Disk Manager. Here's more detailed instructions however.

Convert to `.VHD`: There are plenty of tools out there that allow you to convert a RAW (`.dd`) image to various other extensions. You can use this one liner if you have, or install, VirtualBox.

- In a command line type: `cd %programfiles%\oracle\virtualbox`
- Then the following to actually convert:
   `VBoxManage convertdd C:\Path\ToFile\InputFile.dd C:\Output\File\ConvertedImageName.vhd --format vhd`

I also made a small GUI that is specifically designed to convert any `dd`, `vhd`, `vdi`, `vmdk` image into any other format. Here's the link to that: https://github.com/BiTinerary/ConVertual. It's dead simple, open the executable. Open the file. Click the "VHD" button.

Once you've cloned the drive to a `.VHD` you can mount it in Disk Management

- <kbd>WindowsKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> >> Type `diskmgmt.msc`
- Select "Action" from the menu bar. Then "Attach VHD"
- Run bitlocker on the drive.